# Formula lookup wildcards

Tags: curated-data

When I give the command:

```
FormulaLookup["sphere"]
```

I get no results even though I know there are formulas involving spheres. Do I need to use some kind of wild card format? What is the principle here, are these "entities" or what?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can always execute `FormulaLookup[]` to see all the possible inputs.

Comment: `FormulaLookup[]` does not perform partial or substring searches. Just search the output from `FormulaLookup[]` or `FormulaData[]`, or perform a string match against it.

Comment: This question is valid, IMO. I noticed "BaseballGameScore" and other "Baseball-related" formulas scattered throughout `FormulaData[ ]` output. FormulaLookup["Baseball Game Score"] works, but FormulaLookup["baseball game score"] does not. (other lowercase examples DO work in the doc examples, so this failure is confusing) Given the obvious (?) intent of `FormulaLookup`, it seems less than useful to have to manually text search all of `FormulaData[ ]` to find something.... I think `FormulaLookup` a buggy/incomplete function as of v10.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are formulas for spheres but probably not the ones you're looking for:

```
Select[FormulaLookup[], StringContainsQ[#, "sphere", IgnoreCase -> True] &]
(* {"ChargedSphere", "SphereMomentOfInertia", 
"UniformDensitySphereGravitationalBindingEnergy"} *)
```

There are formulas for other geometric objects:

```
Select[FormulaLookup[], StringContainsQ[#, "area", IgnoreCase -> True] &]
(* {"AnnulusAreaMomentOfInertia", "CircleArea", \
"CircleAreaDiameter", "CircleSectorArea", "EarthquakeRuptureArea", \
"EllipseArea", "HalfDiskAreaMomentOfInertia", \
"HexagonAreaMomentOfInertia", "PentagonAreaMomentOfInertia", \
"QuarterDiskAreaMomentOfInertia", "RectangleArea", \
"RectangleAreaMomentOfInertia", "RegularNGonArea", "TrapezoidArea", \
"TrapezoidAreaMomentOfInertia", "TriangleAreaBH", \
"TriangleAreaMomentOfInertia", "TriangleAreaSSS"} *)
```

"Volume" yields "Spheroid" but not "Sphere"

```
Select[FormulaLookup[], 
 StringContainsQ[#, "volume", IgnoreCase -> True] &]
(* {"EllipsoidVolume", "SpheroidVolume", "TorusVolume"} *)
```

but searching for spheroid doesn't yield anything more than the above "SpheroidVolume".

```
FormulaData["SpheroidVolume"]
(* QuantityVariable["V","Volume"] == 
 4/3 π QuantityVariable["a","Length"]^2 QuantityVariable["c","Length"] *)
```